# Why Does SQL Azure Time(3) datatype render as TimeSpan in MVC? How do I handle these fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database, timespan

Trying to learn MVC.

I have an existing SQL Azure database. Several fields in different tables are defined as time(3), not null

When I try to use those fields in an MVC app, they are converted (interpreted?) as TimeSpan.

Why is that?

How can I get these fields to be recognized as times, not durations? Do I have to alter the fields in the SQL Azure tables? PITA, but doable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework does not have a `time` datatype. All `time` variables are converted to a `System.TimeSpan` variable as explained in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/date-and-time-data). (The article also provides a table of the mapping that happens between SQL Server and the .NET framework).